# Delete developer certificate from Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios, certificate

By mistake I created a developer certificate on my Apple developer account. Now I want to delete it from portal but I could not fond any way to delete it.

Could you please give me an idea/suggestion how to delete certificate from Apple developer portal?

Comment: simply Revoke it.

Answer (score 5):

You can revoke the certificate from apple developer portal , if you've made it by mistake or you want to reset it. Here is the official documentation by apple to [revoke](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) developer certificates.

Answer (score 4):

Revoke the certificate like below screenshot.

[image]