# How do I delete bad certificates from Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode8

I'm new to iOS development, and I can't figure out how to delete bad certificates from Xcode 8. I feel like I've searched everywhere, but I can't find a straightforward answer.

Here's what I tried (couple images below):

In Xcode, I go to `Preferences` and then the `Accounts` tab, and then I click on my Apple ID login. I have 2 different teams - a personal one, and a company enterprise team.

When I click on my personal account, and go to `Manage Certificates`, there's an old certificate that uses an incorrect email I used before, and it says status `Not in Keychain`. But when I right click on it all the options, such as `Delete Certificate` are grayed out. How can I delete this? I really don't want it there because it seems messy.

Then when I go to my company team, and go to `Manage Certificates`, there's a certificate that I had accidentally revoked through the Portal that is now named `Untitled`. And when I right click on it, the `Delete Certificate` is also grayed out.

How can I get rid of these certificates?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: Nope. I still have not.

Comment: Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956336/delete-developer-certificate-from-apple-developer-portal

Answer (score 7):

I had a couple of Untitled certificates as well and after a lot of digging was able to delete them through the keychain app. When you open keychain, under login / My Certificates I had a few certificates which were either expired or revoked causing them to show up as Untitled in Xcode. I simply deleted the certs in keychain and they then disappeared in Xcode.

Comment: The question is about certificates showing in Xcode "not in keychain" So I cant delete in keychain, because they are already gone. But how to remove them in Xcode as well? Have the same issue here.

Comment: This helped remove my "Untitled" certificates. I also have a "not in keychain" certificate which is an active certificate associated with my developer profile that just isn't in my keychain, and so since it is active I don't think it makes sense to try and remove it

Comment: @Tom In my case, I thought as well that the all unwanted certificates were from keychain (because they weren't listed in 'My Certificates') but when I searched in keychain, they were finally listed and I was able to finally remove them.

Leaving this here in case it helps someone.